# What is the best way to sort my php array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

My array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [questionID] => 588
        [answer] => extremely-likely
        [count] => 2
        [percent] => 95%
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [questionID] => 588
        [answer] => extremely-unlikely
        [count] => 2
        [percent] => 95%
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [questionID] => 588
        [answer] => likely
        [count] => 1
        [percent] => 48%
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [questionID] => 588
        [answer] => neither
        [count] => 1
        [percent] => 48%
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [questionID] => 588
        [answer] => unsure
        [count] => 1
        [percent] => 48%
    )

)
```

I have managed to pull back the data I want to display however, when I loop through each of my questions I want to display them in a specific order.

**The order is:**

Extremely Likely

Likely

Neither

Unlikely

Extremely unlikely

Unsure

This is because I want my table to look like below:

[image]

But at the moment it looks like this.

[image]

Sometimes not all of these questions will be there, so if someone hasn't answered extremely likely then that will not be in the array.  In that case it will need to default to the next in the list.

Comment: instead of `extremely-likely` or `likely` kust store a numeric value so you can sort

Comment: If you're getting this from a database, you should sort it in the database.

Comment: check this [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a99780e7e42362f8b89364184908ea59c34738e)

Comment: @Viral Don't `return $a->index > $b->index`, instead `return $a->index - $b->index`.

Comment: @deceze i'll keep that in mind, but this thing works, can you tell me a case when this fails, i'm curious though

Comment: @Viral You're supposed to return a value `< 0`, `0` or `> 0` for `usort` to do its job correctly. You're only ever returning `0` or `1` (`false` or `true`). I don't know whether this would ever cause the sorting to be *incorrect*, but at least it may take a lot *longer* to sort due to it having to repeat comparisons.